# How to Modify Json Response get as object to array?

Tags: php, json

this is json response:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2":
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "age": "19",
            "email": "abc@g.com",
            "gender": "Female",
            "dob": "7 june 1999",
            "add": "sdasdadas"
        }
        }
}
```

I want to convert JSON response as following way:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2":
        [{
            "name": "abc",
            "age": "19",
            "email": "abc@g.com",
            "gender": "Female",
            "dob": "7 june 1999",
            "add": "sdasdadas"
        }]
        }
}
```

I converted my XML response into JSON form and get the object if I have one user details in level2 but I want it in an array in level 2 even have multiple user details or single user details..how can be possible?

Comment: maybe ... `$json = json_decode($response); $json->level1->level2 = [$json->level1->level2]; return json_encode($json);`

Comment: This should be the answer. Post it as one !!!

Comment: But what happens to the data structure if you have already got an array because you had 2 users returned in the response @pr1nc3

Comment: when having multiple user it will return proper :

Comment: {
 "level1": {
  "level2":
  [{
   "name": "abc",
   "age": "19",
   "email": "abc@g.com",
   "gender": "Female",
   "dob": "7 june 1999",
   "add": "sdasdadas"
  },
  {
   "name": "abc",
   "age": "19",
   "email": "abc@g.com",
   "gender": "Female",
   "dob": "7 june 1999",
   "add": "sdasdadas"
  },
  {
   "name": "abc",
   "age": "19",
   "email": "abc@g.com",
   "gender": "Female",
   "dob": "7 june 1999",
   "add": "sdasdadas"
  }]
  }
}

Comment: Yes, but how will you KNOW THAT and therefore NOT run this code

Comment: I would be tempted to say you should do this as part of your XML -> JSON conversion process and not as an after thought

Comment: ya tally return sigle user details in an object and multiple user details returned with json array so i dont understand 
 what to do at the time of xml to json conversion

Comment: So show us how you do that conversion

Comment: its normal xml to json conversion

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code as **@simonecosci** mentioned in the comment.

```
$responseData ='{
    "level1": {
        "level2":
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "age": "19",
            "email": "abc@g.com",
            "gender": "Female",
            "dob": "7 june 1999",
            "add": "sdasdadas"
        }
        }
}';

$json = json_decode($responseData);
$json->level1->level2 = [$json->level1->level2];

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($json));
echo '</pre>';
```

**Expected output:**

> {"level1":{"level2":[{"name":"abc","age":"19","email":"abc@g.com","gender":"Female","dob":"7
>   june 1999","add":"sdasdadas"}]}}

Comment: Dont you think it would have been polite to let @simonecosci convert his comment into an answer

Comment: Thanks :), But I didn't see his comment before answering, that's why I mentioned him in this answer. But now I can delete it.